# SFML's 'intersects' function always returns 'true'

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to know if two rectangles are overlapping each other using `SFML`. Here is my code :

```
if (ball.getLocalBounds().intersects(paddle.getLocalBounds()))
{
    //perform action

}
```

The code would perform the action given that the two rectangles are overlapping each other. But somehow, it always returns `true` in every single cases, even in cases where the two rectangles are not even intersecting each other, such as this :

[image]

As can be seen from the picture, the left paddle and the ball are not even close to each other, but the console is still saying that they're overlapping each other. What is happening here and how do you fix this ?

edit: I tried making a test project with just enough code to reproduce the problem. As from the position of the two rectangles, we can see that they are definitely not intersecting with each other. However, it still says that they are overlapping each other.

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{

RenderWindow window(VideoMode(800, 600), "Test", Style::Close);

RectangleShape r1 = RectangleShape(Vector2f(100, 100));
RectangleShape r2 = RectangleShape(Vector2f(100, 100));

r1.setPosition(0, 0);
r2.setPosition(700, 500);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    Event e;

    while (window.pollEvent(e))
    {
        if (e.type == Event::Closed)
        {
            window.close();
        }
    }

    cout << r1.getLocalBounds().intersects(r2.getLocalBounds()) << endl;

    window.clear();

    window.draw(r1);
    window.draw(r2);

    window.display();
}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Can you construct a complete compileable example in a few lines of code that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Have you tried looking into the actual value returned by `sf::Sprite::getLocalBounds`? What is the difference with the value returned by `sf::Sprite::getGlobalBounds`?

Comment: @Galik I made a test project and added the code of it to the question

Comment: @HungTruong thnx. You didn't really need the window and the loop though, just the rectangles. I think the basic problem is you need `getGlobalBounds` because `getLocalBounds` returns bounds relative to the object, so they will always overlap if you compare them that way. They will all (probably) have `0, 0` as their (local) origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for `getLocalBounds()` say

> The returned rectangle is in local coordinates, which means that it
>   ignores the transformations (translation, rotation, scale, ...) that
>   are applied to the entity. In other words, this function returns the
>   bounds of the entity in the entity's coordinate system.

which gives you an idea as to why the two rectangles are always overlapping. A global `(x: 300, y: 300, w: 500, h: 400)` rectangle would be `(x: 0, y: 0, w: 500, h: 400)` in its own coordinate system.

Both your bounds start at `(x: 0, y: 0)` and thus they always intersect.

Comment: Thanks. I must have misread one of the tutorials from `getGlobalBounds()` to `getLocalBounds()` then.